Power delivery controller confusion
currently I am learning about USB C power delivery. I am talking in the context of power banks. My understanding is, there is a boost converter in the circuit and there is a controller IC in the chip which negotiate with the consumer device and then apply a certain frquency pulse to the boost converter to rise it to the desired voltage level. If this is true I have to use an boost converter which is external to the control chip(which is responsible for negotiation). But after a while i found this. Which is a PD controller. Can somebody explain what is the role of this controller? Does it integrate the boost converter? If it integrates then how can such a tiny chip can supply such a large amount of power? Am i missing something? I am confused. In addition to this can somebody give just a high level role of these kind of pd controller in powerbanks?


... apply a certain frquency pulse to the boost converter to rise it to the desired voltage level.

Well, we can't generalise this as "applying a certain frequency pulse" because the architectures can be different. There are PD controllers that "talk" to the DC/DC converter over a communication line for voltage adjustment whilst there are others that "disturb" the feedback node of the controller/converter individually and adjust the output voltage.

But after a while i found this. Which is a PD controller. Can somebody explain what is the role of this controller?

This is one of those "talking" PD controllers. Read the datasheet, and you'll notice Programmable Power Supply (PPS) applications. The IC is able to communicate some compatible charger/converter ICs (e.g. TI's BQ series) over I2C to adjust the output voltage following a negotiation between the target device (e.g. smartphone).
So...

Does it integrate the boost converter?

... no. The IC is neither a power converter (boost regulator) by itself nor does it include/integrate one. It's an "assistant" tool to a compatible boost regulator: Shoulders the negotiation workload amongst other PD-compatible work and tells the power converter what to do.

That chip is not only a PD controller but it also offers many other things.
Quote from data sheet you linked what a PD controller means : "The USB-PD controller provides the physical layer (PHY) functionality of the USB-PD protocol."
Simply put, you can tell a PD controller to send out messages from your device to the other device (or the E-marked cable). And it will receive the messages sent out by other devices. You send or receive these messages via the I2C interface.
The other things the chip offers are listed in the data sheet. Basically, it can detect and control everything about a Type-C port you need to detect a plug-in or unplug, and the role of the device that was plugged in, even before some data communication or power is delivered to any direction.
But no, it does not integrate a boost converter or battery charging or anything like that. It will simply enable you to do whatever you want with power or data, when device roles, power and data directions have been negotiated.
And tiny chips can convert a lot of power because they are made efficient - and tiny chips may require external swithcing transistors so it does no even have to handle any amount of power, just control the power handling components.
